# Yocoto project, copy prebuild files to target filesystem

Tags: opencv, yocto, bitbake

I've cross-compiled opencv3.4, and it is running well on board. The project is managed through Yocto. so I wrote this `opencv-gl.bb` file to copy prebuilt opencv files to the target filesystem. But after I burned the mirror image to the developed board, I got nothing. It seems the copy command has neveber been executed. Where am I wrong?

```
SUMMARY = "Install opencv 3.4.14 libraries"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

SRC_URI = "\
        file://etc \
        file://usr \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"


## prebuilt library don't need following steps
do_configure[noexec] = "1"
do_compile[noexec] = "1"
do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"
do_install[nostamp] += "1"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/usr/local/bin
    cp -rf ${S}/usr/bin/*  ${D}/usr/local/bin/

    install -d ${D}/usr/local/lib
    cp -rf ${S}/usr/lib/*  ${D}/usr/local/lib/

    install -d ${D}/usr/local/include
    cp -rf ${S}/usr/include/*  ${D}/usr/local/include/

    install -d ${D}/usr/local/share
    cp -rf ${S}/usr/share/*  ${D}/usr/local/share/
}

# let the build system extends the FILESPATH file search path
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/prebuilts:"

FILES_${PN} += " \
    /usr/local/bin/* \
    /usr/local/lib/* \
    /usr/local/include/* \
    /usr/local/share/* \
"
# INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "installed-vs-shipped"
```

the file structure is as follows:

```
wb@ubuntu:~/Yocto/meta-semidrive/recipes-test/opencv-gl$ tree -L 3
.
├── opencv-gl.bb
└── prebuilts
    ├── etc
    │   └── ld.so.conf
    ├── LICENSE
    └── usr
        ├── bin
        ├── include
        ├── lib
        └── share

7 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: Your recipe looks fine, I need to mention that the `file://` scheme looks for `recipe/files` or `recipe/${PN}` or `recipe/${PN}-${PV}` , try renaming `prebuilts` to `files` and remove the line `FILESEXTRAPATHS`.

Comment: yes, it's fine. I forget to add it in `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`. so stupid. Thank you for the comment .  @BelHadjSalem TALEL